# Is it possible to use Facebook SSO with portal users?

Tags: customer-portal, single-sign-on

I know you can use Facebook as an identity provider but it seems to be limited to "regular" users. Can you also use Facebook as an identity provider in the portal?  How does it match back to a user record, just by email address?

Answer (score 12):

You can use it with a portal (see step 11 [in the documentation](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sso_provider_facebook.htm)). The user's Facebook ID is associated with their Salesforce user record. You receive their name and email in the registration handler when they SSO in.

The registration handler can use the incoming `Auth.UserData` to query for a match on an existing user and either create a new user or return an existing user as appropriate.

Here is a sample registration handler that illustrates the above:

```
public class PortalHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
    // createUser is called when there is no existing user linked 
    // to the incoming third party account
    public User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
        User u;

        // Use incoming email for username, since we're working with a 
        // portal user
        List<User> l = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserName = :data.email];
        if (l.size() > 0) {
            u = l[0];
            System.debug('Found existing user record for '+data.username);

            // Update existing record
            u.Email = data.email;
            u.LastName = data.lastName;
            u.FirstName = data.firstName;
            // Useful to save the Facebook ID in a custom field
            u.Facebook_ID__c = data.identifier;

            System.debug('Updating user record for '+data.username);

            update(u);
        } else {
            // Portal users need an associated contact, which, in turn,
            // needs to be associated with an account.
            // For simplicity, just put all contacts on the sForce account
            Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name='sForce'];

            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.AccountId = a.Id;
            c.Email = data.email;
            c.FirstName = data.firstName;
            c.LastName = data.lastName;
            insert(c);

            u = new User();
            Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='High Volume Customer Portal'];

            u.UserName = data.email;
            u.Email = data.email;
            u.LastName = data.lastName;
            u.FirstName = data.firstName;
            u.Facebook_ID__c = data.identifier;
            u.Alias = (data.username != null) ? data.username : data.identifier;
            if (u.Alias.length() > 8) {
                u.Alias = u.Alias.substring(0, 8);
            }
            u.Languagelocalekey = UserInfo.getLocale();
            u.Localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
            u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
            u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            u.ProfileId = p.Id;
            u.ContactId = c.Id;

            System.debug('Returning new user record for '+data.username);
        }

        return u;
    }

    // updateUser is called when there is a match with an existing user
    public void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
        User u = new User(Id=userId);

        u.Email = data.email;
        u.LastName = data.lastName;
        u.FirstName = data.firstName;
        u.Facebook_ID__c = data.identifier;

        System.debug('Updating user record for '+data.username);

        update(u);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way to link them post-registration?

Comment: Yes - this functionality was added in Winter '13 - code sample added to my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: Just wondering if global is still needed here?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Good question. Just checked. It's not. Sample updated.

Comment: @metadaddy Can you please confirm that how salesforce determines that there is a match between exiting user and incoming third party user ?

I am trying to using facebook as a identity provider for portal users but I am facing error so I just want to confirm whether Is the third party user's email-id is checked for a existing user or is there any other approach followed by salesforce ?

Comment: If the user has not already linked their account, then the platform does not determine the match - the registration handler (code above) does. After the user is located or created in the handler and returned to the platform, the relationship is maintained via a 'third-party account link'. You can see this on the user record, and the user (or an admin) can remove the link. The user's Facebook ID is stored on the user record, since the email address may change.